# I get an errorwhen I use the glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

I get an error “[1] " >> STARTING ML RUN FOR RA_base__glmnet" Error in na.fail.default(list(Group = c("RA", "HC", "RA", NA, "RA", "RA",  :    对象里有遺漏值”when I use the glmnet, but I checked that there is no NA in the group. Can anyone help me？I would appreciate

help me how to solve it

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.